# PHP: how to output to browser a png image from disk?

Tags: php

I've a file on a folder on disk I don't want to be visible from web browser

So i create an image.php file that take a file name and must 'do echo' to browser of the image.

Example:

mysite.com/image.php?name=selection.png

must show an image to the user into the browser.

Actually browser ask me to save.
I want to show it, not do ask to download...

i'm using this snippet

```
header("Content-Type: image/png");
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($full_file_name));
header("Content-Disposition: inline; filename='$image'");
readfile($full_file_name);
exit(0);
```

if saved and opened, img is perfect. How to NOT ask to download it?

**EDIT**

- Yes, i need something to use into image tag

*Most of you are replying to my question telling me about image creation, but my question is all about different mode to tell to browser to show something and to ask to user to save something.
NO MORE REPLY ABOUT IMAGE CREATION - YOU'RE OFF-TOPIC !*

*Probably my question, my title, is not clear*, but my question is simple:

**- How to tell to browser to SHOW an image insted to ask user to save it**

Image creation is working

Image usage via imag src is working

**But when user clicks on image, a new tab is opened with the images src as link, because I need to show full size image into browser.
In this situation browser ask me to save !

EDIT:

Removing

```
header("Content-Disposition: inline; filename='$image'");
```

doesn't change Firefox behaviour

Comment: `<img src="http://mysite.com/image.php?name=selection.png">`?

Comment: are you putting the mysite.com/image.php?name=selection.png between an img tag?

Comment: @jcarlos i think he means that the url will look like that at the end.

Comment: Try removing the `Content-Disposition` header.

Comment: @Musa, I'll try Monday, at return to work

Comment: @Musa:sorry, removing Content-Disposition doesn't change behaviour..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try:

```
header("Content-type: image/png");
passthru("cat $full_file_name");
```

Be very careful with the passthru command if you're working with user input, since this function will execute anything you pass it.

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.passthru.php

> When allowing user-supplied data to be passed to this function, use escapeshellarg() or escapeshellcmd() to ensure that users cannot trick the system into executing arbitrary commands.

Comment: It's not working, or well: it's working exactly my readfile. Output is generated, the problem is NOT ask the user to save

Comment: Why use `passthru()` instead of `readfile()`?

Answer (score 2):

To do this, you'd have to base64 encode the image, then output the result. You could use a function like this:

```
<?php

/**
 * Base64 encodes an image..
 *
 * @param [string] $filename [The path to the image on disk]
 * @param [string] $filetype [The image file type, (jpeg, png, gif, ...)]
 */
function base64_encode_image($filename, $filetype) 
{
    if ($filename) 
    {
        $imgBinary = fread(fopen($filename, "r"), filesize($filename));

        return 'data:image/' . $filetype . ';base64,' . base64_encode($imgBinary);
    }
}
```

And then output the result as the source of the image, like:

```
$image = base64_encode_image('...name of file', '... file type');
echo "<img src='$image' />';
```

Comment: sorry, I can't use data:image

Comment: For sake of anoyone reading this, an excellent solution for my issue, but imgBinary is spelled wrong in the return line haha watch out!

Answer (score 2):

You can use PHP's GD library.

in your image.php.

```
<?php
    header('Content-type: image/png');
    $file_name = $_GET['name'];
    $gd = imagecreatefrompng($file_name);
    imagepng($gd);
    imagedestroy($gd);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could alternatively use PHP's [imagepng](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagepng.php):

> imagepng — Output a PNG image to either the browser or a file

```
<?php
$im = imagecreatefrompng("test.png");

header('Content-Type: image/png');

imagepng($im);
imagedestroy($im);
?>
```

Comment: then try to remove the content-disposition in your header.

Answer (score 0):

If your picture paths are stored in a database this method is okay. (I have exampled using MySQLi, adapt this to your Database API)

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `PicturePath` (
  `ID` int(255) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Path` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=0;

    --
INSERT INTO `PicturePath` (`ID`, `Path``) VALUES
(1, 'img/picture.png')
//End DB
// Start script


    $PictureID = $_GET['Name'];

    $Get_Picture = $Conn->prepare("SELECT PicturePath FROM pictures WHERE ID=?");
    $Get_Picture->bind_param('i', $PictureID);
    $Get_Picture->execute();
    $Get_Picture->bind_result($Path);
    $Get_Picture->close();
    echo "<img src='$Path'></img>";
```

The above method is best if you are selecting images using URL Parameters

Otherwise:

```
$Picture = $_Get['Name'];

$Image = imagecreatefrompng($Picture);

header('Content-Type: image/png');

imagepng($Image);
```

might be the solution

Manual here:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagepng.php

Comment: sorry, I've not GD available. And I have no image on DB, i've on disk.